# Typescript 3.7@beta Optional Chaining operator using problem

Tags: javascript, typescript, uri.js

I'm trying to use the Typescript optional chaining operator but it threw this exception:

```
index.ts:6:1 - error TS2779: The left-hand side of an assignment
expression may not be an optional property access.
```

My sample code:

```
const url = URI({
    protocol: 'http',
    hostname: 'example.org' 
})

// This line threw
document.getElementById('output')?.innerHTML = url.toString()
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
const output = document.getElementById('output');
if (output) output.innerHTML = url.toString()
```

This operator is made for accessing deep nest values.

<s>Let's look at `document.getElementById('output')?.innerHTML`. This will return `undefined` (if '#output' not exists) or `string` (if '#output' exists). And you trying to assign `string` to it.</s>

Here you are trying to set a new value for an object property that may not exist.

So yep, optional property access can not be used at the left-hand side of an assignment.

You can read more about it in [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining)

Comment: I don't think the types are the issue here, as you can certainly assign a value of type `string` to a writable variable or property of type `string | undefined`.  The issue is that `foo?.bar` is not writable at all, as it's equivalent to `foo == null ? undefined : foo.bar`, which you can't write to, even with `undefined`.

Comment: @jcalz, yep, sure, I was just tried to explain somehow, that here we are trying assign value to property of some object, that may be not exists. updated

Answer (score 112):

```
objectVariableName!.propertyName = 'some value to assign';
```

> Please note the exclamation symbol i.e,!

Comment: How is this called? is this a ECMAScript implementation?

Comment: @Dazag Looks like it's a non-null assertion operator https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator

Comment: This is a great answer. Helps the code readability. Thanks you

Comment: this is good only if you are sure that objectVariableName exists, you basically teling the compiler not to worry about this being undefined. but if it is undefined you will get an error

Comment: so whats an alternative ?

Comment: The alternative is to use the "if (objectVariableName) objectVariableName.propertyName = value" 
 OR "objectVariableName && (objectVariableName.propertyName = value)". The non-null assertion operator will get you into trouble.

Answer (score 4):

You can also solve this with an early return:

```
const output = document.getElementById('output');
if (!output) return;

output.innerHTML = url.toString()
```

Use it like this for nested properties:

```
if (!item?.text) return;

item.text.text = action.payload.text;
```

https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Answer (score 3):

This very short expression works for me nicely in typescript 4.0.3

```
let domEl: HTMLElement | null = document.querySelector("#app");
domEl && (domEl.style.color = "green");
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

> The Document method getElementById() returns an **Element** object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string.

If we go and see [what properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element#Properties) the **Element** *base class* contains, you will see [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

This means that **it is sure** that an **instance of Element**(the result of `getElementById`) will have an `innerHTML` property, which is why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

in ES12 you can do this with Logical nullish assignment

```
document.getElementById('output')?.innerHTML ??= url.toString()
```

so the assignment will happen only if the left-hand expression is not nullish.

this is just like if you would do

```
if (document.getElementById('output')?.innerHTML) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = url.toString()
}
```

Comment: This is not true, the assignment will happen only if the left-hand expression is nullish. see https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Answer (score 0):

My exception was :

The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be optional property access.

I received this error in typescript "~4.6.2" and solved it like.

```js
let headingDom : HTMLElement | null = document?.querySelector('h1');
if(headingDom) headingDom.textContent = 'Hello World';
```