# Angular error- "The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts"?

Tags: angular, typescript, runtime-error

In my Angular typescript file I have following code. I need help to solve this typescript error

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 setTimeout(() => {
 this.tada = document.querySelectorAll('.highlighted').length;
document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted')?.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';->>Error
        this.fckme();
      }, 50);
    }
```

I am getting the following error

```
The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts(2779)
```

I have created custom pipe where if I get loop through text and search for a word, if word is present in given text I add highlighted class to it so that, I can hilight that word with pink color

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'highlight'
})
export class HiPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(v1: string, v2: string): unknown {
   //some code
    for (const match of matches) {
      value = value.replaceAll(match, `<span class = "highlighted data-${match}">${match}</span>`);
    }
    return v1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just remove the question mark in

```
document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted')?.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
```

for the error.

It should be

```
if(document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted')){
    document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted').style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
}
```

Because that ? making document.querySelector('.highlighted') as optional and in the right we are assigning value to that.

But it will set the pink color in the first item that has the class 'highlighted'. So you need to loop through the elements or add a pink-color class to it. And set the background color of that class item to pink

Try the below code for changing all elements with the class highlighted.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.highlighted');
    if(elements.length){
      elements.forEach((item:HTMLElement) => {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
      })
    }
```

Ckeck this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-services-example-ygmmaq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: On removing `?` from `document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted').style.backgroundColor = 'white'`
` it says `Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
`

Comment: Try the last piece of code. That will work. It has the check, like whether it exists or not.

Comment: I tried above code at `forEach((item:HTMLElement) `it says `Argument of type '(item: HTMLElement) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Element, key: number, parent: NodeListOf<Element>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 107 more.`

Comment: @ParitoshM I have updated the answer with stackblits link. Please check that :)

Comment: @ParitoshM store the result of the querySelector in a variable first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

This may help others for late reply.

```
document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('zsiq_floatmain zsiq_theme1 siq_bL')[0] ['style'].display = 'none'
```

Answer (score 0):

The casting was not set right on the document object

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
setTimeout(() => {
//this.tada = document.querySelectorAll('.highlighted').length;
//you don't need this unless you are trying to apply the pink colour to all class with the selector above. returns an array of all elements with class highlighted
let highlight: Array<HTMLElement> = <HTMLElement>document.querySelectorAll('.highlighted');
//or let highlight:HTMLCollection[] = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('highlighted') as HTMLCollection<HTMLElement>)
highlight.forEach((el:HTMLElement) => {
 if(!el) return;
el.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
});
,0}
}
```

Refer to this link for more info
[Typescript 3.7@beta Optional Chaining operator using problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414515/typescript-3-7beta-optional-chaining-operator-using-problem)

Comment: I am confused can you take whole `ngAfterViewInit()` code and then add your code?

Comment: @ParitoshM removing the lifecycle hook doesn't change the static type checking error.

Comment: Okay but what should I do in place where I have just this single line defined in other function?`document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.highlighted')?.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
`

Comment: I changed the answer. You have to assign the querySelector to a variable.

Comment: If I write as above    `<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.highlighted')?.style.backgroundColor = 'white';`
`  it says `Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)
`

Comment: Yes thats right I am trying to apply the pink colour to all class with the selector above.

Comment: Try getElementsByClassName. Assigning the ```<HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.highlighted')``` to a variable and defining the type it expecting to HTMLElement since the interface implements ElementCSSInlineStyle  should work. I modified the solution above.

Comment: If I use`let highlight: HTMLElement[] = <HTMLElement>document.querySelectorAll('.highlighted');` it says `Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more` and `Conversion of type 'NodeListOf<Element>' to type 'HTMLElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 234 more.`

Comment: If I use `let highlight:HTMLCollection[] = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('highlighted') as HTMLCollection<HTMLElement>)` in forEach it says `Argument of type '(el: HTMLElement) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: HTMLCollection, index: number, array: HTMLCollection[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'el' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'HTMLCollection' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 234 more.`

Comment: Interesting. What about ```let highlight: Array<HTMLElement> = <HTMLElement>document.querySelectorAll('.highlighted');```. All the array properties should exist on the Type ```Array```

Comment: It says `Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more` on `LHS` and `Conversion of type 'NodeListOf<Element>' to type 'HTMLElement' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 234 more.` on `RHS`