Simplify if condition in TypeScript
Can this code be simplified in typescript ? :
        const block = <HTMLElement>(
          document.querySelector('.block')
        );
        if (block) {
          block.style.display = 'none';
        }


(document.querySelector('.block') as HTMLElement)?.style.display = 'none'; is shorter, but I wouldn't say simpler. It's harder to read.

@eventHandler optional chaining is not allowed on the left side in assignments. It will result in a TS2779 error (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414515/typescript-3-7beta-optional-chaining-operator-using-problem)

What exactly is meant by "simplify" here? It's already pretty simple.

@Max It's a poor question. It doesn't explain why they need this simplified. It's pretty simple already. A comment could help the OP but I really think that with 7K rep, the OP should realize this. Otherwise, this question is asking for people to post the really long answer you just posted and no question will ever be chosen as the correct answer. This question is just for debating, not really to solve a real problem, which is the intention of SO.

As it is the code seems fairly simple, its easy to understand, if you want something more condensed because maybe you use it a lot and want to keep it concise, but don't want to make a function like hide thats too specific, then you can create your own abstraction that under certain conditions lets you write expressions more fluently.
For example, I use a lot, simple functions like maybe, map, maybeMap ..etc. That just abstract the nullish aspect from expressions so you can focus on the core logic. It's all a bit borrowed from functional programming, and in typescript it works okay for most things, but full functional programming I think is probably limited by typescript's type system. But for most things you can implement to such an extent is satisfies your requirements. And if the context interests you, you can look up things like Monads, Maybe.. etc. There's a lot to it, but really some of the simple aspect are easy to pick out and use where needed.
So I'll give an example of what I might do if trying to solve the situation you outline.
The initial condition, I would say, is to be able to run some code requiring a variable that may be null. Here it's Element or null. So maybe it's not map in this case, as you don't care about or expect a return, but you could say you're trying to run an effect. So in typescript terms you have an effect that looks like
const f = (input:Element) => { <arbitrary effect code> }

and your input is of type Element | null.
More generally, in this case, you could generalize this as
So you could have a function, we can call it maybeEffect or even just effect which will take an input of type Element|undefined and another argument which defines the effect function to run if the element is not null. So might look something like
const maybeEffect = <T,>(value: T | null, fn: (value: T) => unknown): void => {
  if (value === null) return;
  fn(value);
};

And here, if the input is null, the effect will not run, and it will if the value is not null.
Generally, one thing that's always a question to consider when creating these functions is the fact js has both null and undefined values. I personally look at it like null means the value is intentionally null so it means something somewhat specific, and undefined is like a value that may happen because of many reasons, like just operations that don't always return a value.
So when I write the functions I always use only undefined as the None value and null is an actual value. So normally, when I write a map function it would look like.
const map = <T, R>(value: T | undefined, fn: (v: T) => R) =>
  value === undefined ? undefined : fn(value);

//type: <T, R>(value: T | undefined, fn: (v: T) => R) => R | undefined


But you could equally decide to do
// with null
//type: <T, R>(value: T | null, fn: (v: T) => R) => R | null

//with both null and undefined
type: <T, R>(value: T | null | undefined, fn: (v: T) => R) => R | null | undefined

And any combination really, with inputs, and outputs, maybe it accepts both null and undefined but only return undefined. But it's all very context dependent in my opinion. I'm sure in this case there's a reason for querySelector to return null rather than undefined but when running arbitrary code with optional values I've come to think, after some tries, that using undefined only as the optional value gives most the time the cleanest code.
So going back to your example, another issues is that document.querySelector returns an Element if not null, but Element is not guaranteed to have style attribute, as I think HTMLElement has that. So, again, in inline with our abstractions, you can have cast function that tries to cast the value according to some predicate and either returns it in that type or returns a None value, that lets assume we use undefined for. So you get something like
const maybeCast = <T,>(
  value: unknown,
  predicate: (value: unknown) => boolean,
): T | undefined => (predicate(value) ? (value as T) : undefined);

A function where you specify the type of the value if it satisfies the predicate, and if doesn't you simply return undefined.
So finally, if we look at it together, somewhere you can have a couple functions
const maybeCast = <T,>(
  value: unknown,
  predicate: (value: unknown) => boolean,
): T | undefined => (predicate(value) ? (value as T) : undefined);

const maybeEffect = <T,>(value: T | undefined, fn: (value: T) => unknown): void => {
  if (value === undefined) return;
  fn(value);
};

And then in your code where actually using it, you can have.
maybeEffect(
  maybeCast<HTMLElement>(
    document.querySelector(".block"),
    (value) => value instanceof HTMLElement,
  ),
  (el) => {
    el.style.display = "none";
  },
);

And if you also declare
const maybeHTMLElement = (value: unknown) =>
  maybeCast<HTMLElement>(value, (value) => value instanceof HTMLElement);


You can express it as
maybeEffect(maybeHTMLElement(document.querySelector(".block")), (el) => {
  el.style.display = "none";
});


or
const block = maybeHTMLElement(document.querySelector(".block"));

maybeEffect(block, (el) => {
  el.style.display = "none";
});

which is a bit more concise and I think equally readable if you know the meanings of the functions and you have a decent convention around them. Which I think is fairly easy to do.
Hope it made sense and helps a bit,
Here's a link to typescript playground if you wanna see how it looks there.

I can see there's some good stuff in your answer but I can't help but to think it's overkill.

ahahah, its funny I was thinking the exact same thing reading over it . But it's cause when I use this I have hundreds of expressions manipulating multivariable expressions with potentially undefined data so the impact is huge for me at least in terms of not checking undefined everywhere. For this it's probably a bit much but can be nice if doing a lot of stuff.
